# Count of 3 distinct values by country + join

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm trying to figure out how to count how many customers are in each status by country.

I started with joining the two tables `customers_customers` & `customer_status` to get the country values for each customer. This will get me a one-off answer for a specific country and status. However, I can't figure out how to count how many customers (by country) are in each status. (*Example of desired output below*)

```
SELECT COUNT (customers_customers.customerID)
FROM customers_customers
LEFT JOIN customer_status
ON customers_customers.customerID = customer_status.customerID
WHERE customers_customers.Country = "US" and customer_status.status = "In Progress";
```

**customers_customers**

| customerID | country |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | US |
| 2 | CA |
| 3 | UK |
| 4 | GB |
| 5 | US |

**customer_status**

| customerID | status |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | In Progress |
| 2 | Done |
| 3 | Not Started |
| 4 | Done |
| 5 | In Progress |

***Ultimately, I'm looking for this output:***

| Country | Not Started | In Progress | Done |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| US | 2 | 3 | 1 |
| UK | 1 | 6 | 2 |
| GB | 2 | 5 | 1 |
| CA | 2 | 1 | 7 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the aggregate function SUM by condition and group by country.

```
SELECT
  country,
  SUM(CASE WHEN cs.status = 'Not Started' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS NotStarted,
  SUM(CASE WHEN cs.status = 'In Progress' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS InProgress,
  SUM(CASE WHEN cs.status = 'Done' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Done
FROM customers_customers cc
JOIN customer_status cs ON cc.customerID = cs.customerID
GROUP BY country
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=939df49981ca3423db691783a7977a75)

Comment: Or You can use `COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE cs.status = 'Not Started')` instead of `SUM(...)`.

Comment: I ended up using SUM(CASE WHEN...) and it worked! I tried using COUNT(*) FILTER and when I kept hitting a wall, I read that it doesn't work with Google BQ, which is what I am using. Thank you for the help!

Comment: You got it! :) Learning how to use this site haha

Answer (score 1):

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=495d12291669c4be251aa7221bf20d69)

```sql
select
  cc.country as "Country",
  count(*) filter (where cs.status = 'Not Started') as "Not Started",
  count(*) filter (where cs.status = 'In Progress') as "In Progress",
  count(*) filter (where cs.status = 'Done') as "Done"
from 
  customers_customers cc left join customer_status cs
    on cc."customerID" = cs."customerID"
group by 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider below quite generic approach

```
select * from (
  select * replace(replace(status, ' ', '_') as status)
  from customers_customers
  join customer_status
  using (customerID)
)
pivot (count(customerID) for status in ('Not_Started', 'In_Progress', 'Done'))
```

if applied to sample/dummy data in your question - output is

[image]